# Making a 2D Game: Figuring out sprite sizes?

Tags: sprites, game-maker, art

I'm currently making a 2D game as a school project using Game Maker and its language. My concern however is around the spriting and art...

I can't figure out how to correctly size everything so it shows up correctly on the end product.
I originally used a temporary 32x32 character but it looks very small when I have the "Room Size" in Game Maker set to 720p...

Is this something that I need to change size-wise on Game Maker, such as changing how far in the perspective/camera is, or do I have to set actual dimension rules? I'm unsure of how to do this properly.

Comment: As an example, Rpg Maker does 24x24 for icons, 32x32 for tiles and actor graphics, and I believe 128x128 for animations. The standard seems to be 32x32 or 64x64. This really depends on your game, though.

Comment: Alright thanks. and how do I make this work well? When I press play everything is so small- do I need to have it zoomed on the character or change camera angles or something? or is it not supposed to be 1080?

Comment: See documentation about views [1](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/windows%20and%20views/views/index.html), [2](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20rooms/views.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working on a 2D game, you don't have a perspective camera, but a projection camera. However, you don't need to deal with its settings, because Game Maker lets you deal with the problem by simply using [*Views*](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20rooms/views.html).

A view lets you show the player only a portion of the whole room. This is useful both to hide some parts of the level to limit the player sight, and to keep the arts and graphics proportioned to a given aspect ratio, independently of the room width.

Read [the documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20rooms/views.html) to learn more about Views, View Ports, and experiment until you get the expected result.